# How to create a task that runs forever after the bot is online

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a task that runs forever every 10 seconds once the bot is online but I'm getting a lot of errors and tried different things

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 10)
async def check_votes():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    voted_users = votedb.votes.find({"voted": "true"})
    for user in voted_users:
        vote_time = user.get("vote_time")
        elapsed_time = now - vote_time
        if elapsed_time > datetime.timedelta(seconds=30):
            votedb.votes.update_one({"user_id": user.get("user_id")}, {"$set": {"voted": "false"}})
```

I've tried doing asyncio.run(check_votes()) and check_votes.start() but none of them seem to work. If I put check_votes.start() in the `setup_hook` it only runs 1 time when the bot is online.

Comment: Do you launch your loop at bot init ? should be something like `@bot.listen()` followed by `async def on _ready():` then by `check_vote.start()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should still put it in the `setup_hook` instead of other places like `on_ready`. The `setup_hook` should look like:

```py
async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
    check_votes.start()
```

Also, you can use `wait_until_ready` to start the `tasks.loop` when the client's internal caches are all ready. In your case (change bot to how you name bot):

```py
@check_votes.before_loop
async def before_check_votes():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
```